# cant set Host in CURL PHP

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping, web-crawler

I am unable to set the host in curl. It still shows as localhost if i use the following code

```
function wget($url)
        {

            $agent= 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:35.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/35.0.1';
            $curlHeaders = array (
                    'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
                    'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate',
                    'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5',
                    'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:35.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/35.0.1',
                    'Connection: Keep-Alive',
                    'Pragma: no-cache',
                    'Referer: http://example.com/',
                    'Host: hostname',
                    'Cache-Control: no-cache',
                    'Cookie: visid_incap_185989=9v1q8Ar0ToSOja48BRmb8nn1GFUAAAAAQUIPAAAAAABCRWagbDIfmlN9NTrcvrct; incap_ses_108_185989=Z1orY6Bd0z3nGYE2lbJ/AXn1GFUAAAAAmb41m+jMLFCJB1rTIF28Mg==; _ga=GA1.3.637468927.1427699070; _gat=1; frontend=rqg7g9hp2ht788l309m7gk8qi7; _gat_UA-1279175-12=1; __utma=233911437.637468927.1427699070.1427699078.1427699078.1; __utmb=233911437.2.10.1427699078; __utmc=233911437; __utmz=233911437.1427699078.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); __utmt_UA-1279175-1=1; _cb_ls=1; _chartbeat2=S0WVXDwMWnCFBgQp.1427699081322.1427699232786.1; PRUM_EPISODES=s=1427699568560&r=http%3A//example.com/'

            );
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $curlHeaders);
            curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
            $result=curl_exec($ch);
            return $result;
        }
```

I use `fiddler` to track the network requests. where I found the host is still as localhost
[image]

If I load this same Link in browser i get as following in `fiddler`

[image]

I need my specified domain to be accessed. How can I achieve this?
Note: I am aware that host name should not contain the protocol.

**Alternatively**

Also i would like to know is it possible to get the source code of a website the could be seen in browser through terminal?

Comment: I would suggest to start with adding `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);` to your code and checking what is actually happening in the backgound. You will probably get much more information than from fiddler.

Comment: I've tried your code. Other file receive header `Host: hostname`. I think you need something like that my website to be masked as "stackoverflow.com", which is difficult to do. You can modify headers, but not HTTP protocol (not easy to do).

Comment: So I ran this on several host I have access to by feeding the url into the the function call and it runs flawlessly. You need to check a few things and provide more information. 1) How is that URL being feed into the function call, are you certain it is set correctly. ie. if you call $result = wget($someurl); Make sure $someurl is set correctly. 2) Check your hostfile and proxy settings.

Comment: Set the full URL into CURLOPT_URL.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming we are *not* trying spoof the `Host` header, omit the `Host` header altogether and let curl sort it out. In this case, just remove `'Host: hostname',` because you already get curl to automatically set this with your code near the bottom with `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);`.

If you really want to set the `Host` header yourself, then just replace

```
'Host: hostname',
```

with

`"Host: ". parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST),`

(Note: This function doesn't work with relative URLs.)

Answer (score 2):

try like this,

```
  curl_init('XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Host: subdomain.hostname.com'));
```

Comment: try like this,
  
    $ipaddress='desired_ip';
    $url='path/to/file?';
    curl_init('http://'.$ipaddress.$url);

Comment: I am working with windows and xampp.. would it be any problem with it?

Comment: If a single request is sent through this code and then when i try to load this page in browser its asks for captcha

Answer (score 1):

If you are using windows and xampp then try to use **virtual host** rather than localhost, then it will start working, I did the same.

Comment: how to use virtual host

Answer (score 1):

According to [HTTP](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.23) quick specification read, I assume your problems are happening because of improper `Host` header being send. I was able to download some websites with following code:

```
function wget($url, $follow = true) {

    $host = parse_url($url);

    $agent       = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:35.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/35.0.1';
    $curlHeaders = array(
        'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate',
        'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5',
        'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:35.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/35.0.1',
        'Connection: Keep-Alive',
        'Pragma: no-cache',
        'Referer: http://example.com/',
        'Host: ' . $host['host'] . (isset($host['port']) ? ':' . $host['port'] : null), // building host header
        'Cache-Control: no-cache',
        'Cookie: visid_incap_185989=9v1q8Ar0ToSOja48BRmb8nn1GFUAAAAAQUIPAAAAAABCRWagbDIfmlN9NTrcvrct; incap_ses_108_185989=Z1orY6Bd0z3nGYE2lbJ/AXn1GFUAAAAAmb41m+jMLFCJB1rTIF28Mg==; _ga=GA1.3.637468927.1427699070; _gat=1; frontend=rqg7g9hp2ht788l309m7gk8qi7; _gat_UA-1279175-12=1; __utma=233911437.637468927.1427699070.1427699078.1427699078.1; __utmb=233911437.2.10.1427699078; __utmc=233911437; __utmz=233911437.1427699078.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); __utmt_UA-1279175-1=1; _cb_ls=1; _chartbeat2=S0WVXDwMWnCFBgQp.1427699081322.1427699232786.1; PRUM_EPISODES=s=1427699568560&r=http%3A//example.com/'
    );
    $ch          = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $curlHeaders);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, $follow); // following redirects or not
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    $result      = curl_exec($ch);
    return $result;
}

echo(wget('http://example.com'));
```

Anyway this function is not an universal build. Personally I would add saving cookies between redirection requests etc. Essential change is within 'Host' header line. I'm building there proper `Host` header based on full `$url` provided to function.

Comment: I found the website that I am trying to scrape is using JS to validate/verify whether the request is sent through browser. if it opened with browser the host is example.com and it loads for a file `example.com/verify.js`. So if the request is sent through browser it loads for `localhost/verify.js`.  Before that the above code returns a javascript that i could able to see in browser's inspect element.

Comment: @DharanBro Quite not understand your comment. Is it working or it still has some issues?

Answer (score -1):

Set the full URL into `CURLOPT_UR`L.